# Trying to parse all URLs from a file or in this case a remote URL

Tags: ruby, linux, uri, open-uri

I'm trying to parse 3 arguments (this works) and request a file that has a bunch of txt and URLs in it. I'm trying to put each URL into an array I have try with some regexp with no luck and also with `scan(URI.regexp)` et.c and cant see to figure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'

HOST=ARGV[0]
ID=ARGV[1]
VERSION=ARGV[2]
MYLINKS = Array.new

file = open("http://#{HOST}/v1/dc/manifest/#{ID}/#{VERSION}").read

file.each_line do |line|
    #puts "doing #{line}" # this works..
    MYLINKS << URI.extract(line, ['http', 'https'])
end
```

PS: the file is a JSON file. This is all working on a Bash script but I'm migrating it to Ruby. In the Bash script I download the file to `/tmp` then I parse it with `awk`/`tr` etc.

Comment: Have you considered an API client like HTTParty, which will parse the JSON for you?

Comment: I did but then I though that since I just need to strip out urls's I may not need it.. and I have no idea of json.. how will you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an API client like [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) you don't really have to know JSON, because responses are parsed into a data structure you can extract. You can start with a simple class:

```
require 'httparty'

class MyApi
  include HTTParty
  format :json
end
```

Then you can do the following:

```
response = MyApi.get("http://#{HOST}/v1/dc/manifest/#{ID}/#{VERSION}")
```

and the response will be parsed into a hash structure that you'll be able to pull your URLs from in a robust way.

If your API requires authentication or posting data, it is easy to add. There are [several examples](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples/) in the gem itself, so you can see how various things are done.

Comment: ok what im doing is something like file = MyApi.get("http://#{HOST}/v1/dc/manifest/#{ID}/#{VERSION}") then I file.each do |item| puts item['manifest']['files']['url'] end but is not working when I add the 'url' also on irb I can get all the sub hashes inside ['manifest']['files'] and I can only get the url if I expecify which one.. like for example puts file['manifest']['files']['1']['url'] <-- this does work on irb but since I need to get ALL url's this is why I use .each but it gives me a cant convert to string error or similar

Comment: Extracting values from a hash is a different topic. It could easily be another StackOverflow question. In fact if you post a sample hash and your dilemma, I'm sure you'd get answers quickly.

Comment: ok I created this one, take a look since I added more examples maybe it rings a bell.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814456/extracting-values-from-a-hash

Comment: Sorry I realized that it will only automatically parse as JSON if the URL ends in '.json'; otherwise, you have to explicitly mention the format. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by replacing the constant `MYLINKS` by a variable, e.g. `my_links`. This will allow you to add elements to the `my_links` array. Ruby will assume that any name starting with an uppercase letter (e.g. `MYLINKS`, `MyLinks`) is a constant.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'

HOST=ARGV[0]
ID=ARGV[1]
VERSION=ARGV[2]
my_links = []

file.each_line do |line|
    my_links << URI.extract(line, ['http', 'https'])
end
```

Comment: @luiism hello, thanks for the reply makes sense but still not stripping the URL's from each line :-(