# Rails: How to send a http get request with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, httprequest, httparty

I'm trying to use an external API to get some information

```
  address=self.address
  response = HTTParty.get("http://api.map.baidu.com/geocoder/v2/?address=#{address}&output=json&ak=5dfe24c4762c0370324d273bc231f45a")
  decode_response =  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)
```

However, the `address` is in chinese, so I need to convert into UTF-8 code, 
if not I'll get `URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?):` How to do it?

I tried `address=self.address.force_encoding('utf-8')`, but it does not work, maybe I should use other method instead?

UPDATE:

```
  uri = "http://api.map.baidu.com/geocoder/v2/?address=#{address}&output=json&ak=5dfe24c4762c0370324d273bc231f45a"
  encoded_uri = URI::encode(uri)
  response = HTTParty.get(encoded_uri)
  decode_response =  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)
  self.latitude = decode_response['result']['location']['lat']
```

and I get `can't convert HTTParty::Response into String`. What's wrong with it?

[I found something here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814456/extracting-values-from-a-hash), I think I'll need to tell Httparty explicityly to parse it with JSON?

Comment: try to encode the URL first before passing to HTTParty

Comment: I tried and failed. It must be something I have missed. Could please show me some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save this to a file 'geo.rb' and run `ruby geo.rb`

```
require 'uri'
require 'httparty'

address = "中国上海"
uri = "http://api.map.baidu.com/geocoder/v2/?address=#{address}&output=json&ak=5dfe24c4762c0370324d273bc231f45a"
encoded_uri = URI::encode uri
puts HTTParty.get(encoded_uri)
```

Comment: This works. But I get `can't convert HTTParty::Response into String` when using it. See my update

Comment: Well. You do not have to now. It seems like I have found the solution